# class-code with hibernate reverse engineering

Tags: hibernate

I am producing my hibernate entities using hibernate tools ant task (jdbcconfiguration + hbm2java).

I need to add some business logic to my class.

According to [this](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/12/14/hibernate-class-generation-with-hbm2java.html?page=6), I can use the The *class-code* Meta Attribute in the mapping file or create a base class with the *generated-class* meta attribute, However as I am using *jdbcconfiguration* I have no mapping file.

How would I achieve this using *jdbcconfiguration*?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it out, I added the flowing to the reveng.xml file

```
<table catalog="CATALOG_HERE" schema="SCHEMA_HERE" name="NAME_HERE">
    <meta attribute="class-code">
        *CODE HERE*
    </meta>
</table>
```